# Problems understanding the topological definition on continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am not a native speaker in English, so please forgive me if I cannot make my point clear. I am currently reading Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis and I met some difficulties when I was reading the paragraphs on continuity. I know it is proved that, for a continuous f: M -> N, if the preimage of some open subset of N is open, but I seems to have f a counter-example.

Take the famous counter-example that shows the inverse of a continuous function is not necessarily continuous: $f$ maps $t$ in $M=(-\pi,\pi]$ to a unit disc $N=\{(x,y):x=\cos t,y=\sin t\}$. If we define the metric on $N$ to be the difference of the central angles of two points, it seems to me that $N$ is both open and closed, while its preimage $M$ is neither.

I know I am definitely wrong but I cannot see where I made a mistake. It would be great help if someone can show me where the mistake is.

Comment: Read the section about Inheritance

Answer (score 4):

The preimage of $N$ under $f$ is indeed $(-\pi,\pi]$; but that set *is* both open and closed in the domain $M$. (It's neither open nor closed in $\Bbb R$, but fortunately that's not relevant to this particular function.)